# Is it possible to rewrite such code in Java8 streams?

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I was trying to adapt it to Java 8 streams:

```
public boolean isProcessionRestricted(CommonMessage message) {
    if (message.getClass() == BonusMessage.class) {
        log.debug("Staring validating BonusMessage: '{}'", message);
        BonusMessage bonusMessage = (BonusMessage) message;
        Optional<BonusTriggerConfig> config = bonusTriggerConfigRepository.getCached();
        if (config.isPresent()) {
            BonusTriggerConfig bonusTriggerConfig = config.get();
            List<BonusRewardConfig> rewardConfigs = bonusTriggerConfig.getRewardConfigs();
            if (!rewardConfigs.isEmpty()) {
                return rewardConfigs.stream()
                        .map(BonusRewardConfig::getBonusTypeId)
                        .noneMatch(bonusTypeId -> bonusTypeId == bonusMessage.getBonusTypeId());
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

but I faced the problem with checking if collection is empty in streams. The "streammest" thing which I get looks like this:

```
@Override
public boolean isProcessionRestricted(CommonMessage message) {
    if (message.getClass() == BonusMessage.class) {
        log.debug("Staring validating BonusMessage: '{}'", message);
        BonusMessage bonusMessage = (BonusMessage) message;
        return bonusTriggerConfigRepository.getCached()
                .map(bonusTriggerConfig -> {
                    List<BonusRewardConfig> rewardConfigs = bonusTriggerConfig.getRewardConfigs();
                    return !rewardConfigs.isEmpty() && rewardConfigs.stream()
                            .map(BonusRewardConfig::getBonusTypeId)
                            .noneMatch(bonusTypeId -> bonusTypeId == bonusMessage.getBonusTypeId());
                }).orElse(false);
    }
    return false;
}
```

but still I don't like it.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are asking.  If you are asking whether it is possible, then you have clearly shown that the answer is yes.  If you're asking how to improve it, you are better off by going to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: is 'noneMatch' or 'anyMatch'? !rewardConfigs.isEmpty() && rewardConfigs.stream()...noneMatch(...) doesn't make scenes to me

Comment: @123-xyz :), the behavior are different between `noneMatch` and `anyMatch` that I also have tried. you can see my edited answer, I removed the `anyMatch` solution immediately after I wrote it down. the OP only want to return `false`  simply if the collection is empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Optional#filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) to filtering the empty collection instead, for example:

```
return bonusTriggerConfigRepository.getCached()
        .map(bonusTriggerConfig -> bonusTriggerConfig.getRewardConfigs())
        // v--- filter the empty configs out
        .filter(rewardConfigs-> !rewardConfigs.isEmpty())
        .map(rewardConfigs -> rewardConfigs.stream()
            .map(BonusRewardConfig::getBonusTypeId)
            .noneMatch(bonusTypeId -> bonusTypeId == bonusMessage.getBonusTypeId())
        )
        .orElse(false);
```

Comment: This answer shows that if you know how to write code, you can do it even without using third-party libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless @Joe C's comments, I'm not sure if it's better to move this OP to Code Review. But I learned something from OP about how to write concise code with Java 8 Stream API, First, Here is my first try with [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) (I didn't try with native stream APIs because it's too boring to me...)

```
public boolean isProcessionRestricted(CommonMessage message) {
    return StreamEx.of(message)
        .select(BonusMessage.class)
        .peek(m -> log.debug("Staring validating BonusMessage: '{}'", m))
        .anyMatch(m -> bonusTriggerConfigRepository.getCached()
                .map(btc -> StreamEx.of(btc.getRewardConfigs())
                        .noneMatch(brc -> brc.getBonusTypeId() == m.getBonusTypeId())).orElse(false));
}
```

(If there are some compile errors, please help to update my answer).
But logic looks too complicate to me. Here are the codes I may write if I was the programmer:

```
public boolean isProcessionRestricted(CommonMessage message) {
    if (!(message insanceof BonusMessage && bonusTriggerConfigRepository.getCached().isPresent())) {
        return false;
    }

    log.debug("Staring validating BonusMessage: '{}'", message);     
    int restrictedBonusTypeId = ((BonusMessage) message).getBonusTypeId();
    List<BonusRewardConfig> rewardConfigs = bonusTriggerConfigRepository.getCached().get().getRewardConfigs();
    return rewardConfigs.size() > 0 && rewardConfigs.stream()
            .noneMatch(brc -> brc.getBonusTypeId() == restrictedBonusTypeId);
}
```

What I learned or suggest:

1. Forget Stream API, It just looks cool, but not that cool. Writing concise code with/without Stream API is really cool.
2. Although I like Lambdas and Stream API. However, how to write concise code with Stream API is much more challenge to me, comparing the for-loop/if/while. it's better to go over the Stream API again and again, and do more practices before you start to use the stream API in real product.
3. Always prefer to [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex). Sometimes it's really boring to write code with native Stream API. [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) provides a lot of shorter and convenient ways to accomplish your tasks.

Forget stream

Comment: Sounds not bad. Will try to implement.